# Find Test Coverage as part of Build process

Tags: unit-testing, test-coverage

How do I find the Test Coverage of my code during the build process automatically, and ensure that if coverage is below 80%, build should fail.
So, is it possible that as part of my gradle build process when the test case runs, there should also be another testcase, which should find the test-coverage percentage and apply assertions to ensure coverage %age > 80?

Can we get this through JUnits only. I don;t want to externally check the coverage in eclipse.

Comment: we need some more information. What stack are you developing on, any build servers and so on...

Comment: I have a springboot project with embedded tomcat. Rest APIs are exposed as part of the project. So, as part of my gradle build, can I also find the test coverage and ensure that %age of coverage > 80% or build failure...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, please have a look at this project:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html